# how to use placeholder in laravel 5.4 form?

Tags: php, html, laravel-5.4

**i want to use placeholder in my laravel form.but its not working.can you please give some fruitful solution?TIA**

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    {!! Form::select('asign_list[]', $employees, null,
    ['class' => 'form-control select2', 'required'=>'required','multiple'])!!}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass placeholder in options array like this:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    {!! Form::select('asign_list[]', $employees, null,
    ['class' => 'form-control select2',
     'required'=>'required',
     'multiple', 
     'placeholder' => 'Sample placeholder'])!!}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this -

```
{{ Form::select('age', [
   'young' => 'Under 18',
   'adult' => '19 to 30',
   'adult2' => 'Over 30'], 1
) }}
```

It will generate this html -

```
<select name="age">
  <option value="young">Under 18</option>
  <option value="adult" selected="selected">19 to 30</option>
  <option value="adult2">Over 30</option>
</select>
```